# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Info.<init>(Info.java:168)
        at Rcon.data(Rcon.java:130)
        at Rcon$1.run(Rcon.java:105)
```

Line 168 is at bot.redScore = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

```
    else if(str.indexOf("current score") != -1) {
        pattern = "Team \\\"(\\w+)\\\" current score \\\"(\\d+)\\\"";
        p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        matcher = p.matcher(str);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            if(matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("Red")) {
                bot.redScore = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

            }
            else if(matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("Blue")) {
                bot.blueScore = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            }
            cmd = "score";
        }
    }
```

I have no clue why I keep getting this error.
The str that is being parsed using regex is:

```
Processing: Team "Red" current score "1" with "1" players
```

When I am running only this part by itself, it works fine.
But when I am running the whole program I get this exception.

bot.blueScore and bot.redScore are being declared in another class as follows:

```
int redScore = 0;
int blueScore = 0;
```

Also I have checked the contents of matcher.group(2), and it returns an integer, anywhere from 0 to 10.
Any ideas? I have been struggling with this for hours now.

Thanks!

Comment: Hours?  Don't you have an IDE with a debugger?  I would have stepped through the first time it happened to me to see how actual behavior was conflicting with my expectations.

Answer (score 4):

`bot` is likely to be `null`. Make sure it is not null (initialize it)

That said, you should learn to read exceptions - this is a very core skill. `NullPointerException` is the most common exception - you already identified the line, and if you check the documentation of the exception, you will see that it usually occurs when a reference is `null` and you are trying to access methods/fields on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a null pointer exception look for expressions on the line of the form `x.y` and ask yourself why `x` is null.  In your case either `bot` or `matcher` must be null.  Since you got into that line using `matcher` on the previous line, your variable `bot` is null.

Comment: You also forgot the case of unboxing null values. But it does not seem to be applicable here.

Comment: Good point, Alex.  I also forgot array expressions like `a[i]` where a can be null, etc. :)